# Why does Perl crash when using LibXML after a fork?

Tags: perl

I'm having a hard time with this problem, but I've narrowed it down to using XML::LibXML after I've done a fork in Perl.  I'm running Strawberry Perl 5.12.0 on Windows XP, and XML::LibXML 1.70.

I'm have a script where I need to run several processes concurrently, take the XML output and process the results.  If I run this on a Solaris machine, it runs just fine and I have no issues.  However, if I run this on Windows, I get a crash window stating that 'perl.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close.'

Here is a sample program that will generate the error:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
use Try::Tiny;

my $cmds = ['cmd1', 'cmd2'];
my @pids = ();
foreach my $cmd (@{$cmds}) {

    my $pid = fork();

    if ($pid) {

        # parent
        push (@pids, $pid);
    } elsif ($pid == 0) {

        XML::LibXML->load_xml(string=>'<root />'); # <-- this will crash it
        exit 0;
    }
}

foreach my $ch_pid (@pids) {

    try {

        waitpid($ch_pid, 0);
    } catch {

        carp("Error on waitpid: $!");
    };
}
exit 0;
```

If I only have one process, or if I don't fork, then it will work successfully.  If I remove the load_xml call (and have nothing in the child), then it will work successfully.

Does anyone know what may be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behavior with ActivePerl 5.12.2 Build 1202 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Special considerations need to be made when [using XML::LibXML with threads](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML#THREAD-SUPPORT). Some of these (particularly about initially loading the module) will also pertain to forks.

You can try removing the compile time load (the `use XML::LibXML;` line), and instead load in the module once you have forked:

```
} elsif ($pid == 0) {
    require XML::LibXML;
    XML::LibXML->load_xml(string=>'<root />');
    exit 0;
}
```

Comment: When running on Windows, perl's `fork` is actually creating a new thread, so this is even more relevant.

Comment: I just tried both of those suggestions, and I still get the same error message.

Comment: @Joel, since you're using threads anyway, why not avoid `fork` completely?

Comment: @ikegami, How stable are threads in Perl, or are they OK to use in production code?  I was under the impression that threads in Perl were kind of a hack and should be avoided.  I do agree with you, for what I'm doing here threads would be a better solution.

Comment: @Joel, They're stable, and there's nothing hackish about them. `fork` is the hackish one as it's not something Windows can do. That's why it's emulated using threads.

Comment: @ikegami, Thanks, that worked for me.  If you put that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Joel, It's ok, give it to the other Eric. I was just helping you implement his solution :)