# perl with libxml silently crashing in Windows 10 inside loop with fork

Tags: perl, libxml2, strawberry-perl

I'm using perl 5.24.4 under Windows 10 that have the latest LibXML installed (2.0134). Below is the code that crashes on Windows 10 (It works on Linux)

### crash.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use Utils;
use Log::Log4perl;


Log::Log4perl->init('logger.conf');
my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger();

sub generate_word_stats_for_chunk
{
    return Utils::load_sql();
}

my $num_process = 4; 
my @modes = (1,3,5);

foreach my $mode (@modes) {


    my @pid_list;
    $logger->info("Forking $num_process");
    for my $i (0 .. $num_process - 1) {
        my $pid = fork();
        $logger->logconfess("Unable to fork $!") if not defined $pid;
        if ($pid == 0) {
            # child process
            generate_word_stats_for_chunk($i);
            sleep 2;

            # make sure that the child process exit
            exit;
    }
    # parent
    # Store the PIDs, so that waitpid() can call them later
    push @pid_list, $pid;
}

for my $pid (@pid_list) {
    waitpid $pid, 0;
}
$logger->info("finished mode $mode");
```

### Utils.pm

```
package Utils;

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;
use Log::Log4perl;

my $logger = Log::Log4perl->get_logger();

sub load_sql 
{

    $logger->info("parsing XML");   
    my $dom;

    eval {
        $dom  = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'sql.xml');
    };
    if ($@) {
        $logger->error("parse error $@");
        return;
    }
    $logger->info("finished parsing XML");  

    # dummy
    return {};
}

# perl package ends with 1
1;
```

### sql.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<sqls>    
    <sql name="CREATE_COMMODITY_META">
        test
    </sql>      
</sqls>
```

Running crash.pl gives me the following output

```
INFO main::(crash.pl:37) Forking 4
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:31) finished parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:31) finished parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:31) finished parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:31) finished parsing XML
INFO main::(crash.pl:62) finished mode 1
INFO main::(crash.pl:37) Forking 4
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
INFO Utils::load_sql(Utils.pm:21) parsing XML
```

The code works if I remove the `Utils::load_sql()` statement. This *might* be similar to [Why does Perl crash when using LibXML after a fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001322/why-does-perl-crash-when-using-libxml-after-a-fork), but I have some doubts as the code in that post works only machine. My code actually works if you remove the outer loop (e.g. the `foreach my $mode...` ). Also another reason why I doubt it is that post is already 8 years old.

Also, why isn't the eval statement in `Utils.pm` not catching the crash?

Comment: Most likely, you're running afoul of XML::LibXML not being threadsafe enough. My recommendation is to avoid `fork()` and instead launch real child processes.

Comment: The [note on thread support](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML#THREAD-SUPPORT) in `XML::LibXML`, linked in the post you link to, isn't "_8 years_" old; also, `fork` on Windows is emulated using threads (as Windows has no fork), which can only make it trickier.  So, since there _is_ a problem, I'd try changing to threads (instead of forking) and then follow carefully what docs say on how to work with the module under threads.

Comment: "_code actually works if you remove the outer loop_" -- I don't see that the outer loop does anything, other than triggering 3x as many threads of execution.  This alone may be a factor: issues with threads/forks very often don't come up in every run, and have far more chance to show when it's busier (more threads or processes)

Comment: `fork` is a unix concept that doesn't exist in Windows. Perl poorly emulates it using threads in Windows. It's best to avoid `fork` on Windows.

Comment: ...Do you have the problem if you just use threads directly?

Comment: @Ikegami @Corion @zdim The code are meant to be run on a linux box but I do most of my development on a Windows machine though. I believe process are more robust and mature in Linux; thus I prefer to stick with `fork()`

Comment: uh, so what's your question, then?

Comment: And yeah, it works fine with threads without fork